# Visual Studio 2015 Intellisense error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

I am working on a C++ project in Visual Studio 2015. The compilation works fine but the editor keeps showing me the following error:

command-line error: invalid maco definition: SEQAN_C++11_STANDARD=ON

autocomplete is not working for the same reason I think.

Is this a problem with my Intellisense?

Comment: That's not a valid preprocessor symbol, which is probably why you get the message. As for why it builds, it might be because the actual compiler, and the C++-checker in IntelliSense uses different parsers, and you might have something which simply confuses the IntelliSense parser.

Comment: That's odd because the place where error shows is right at the start of file, irrespective of what I write over there: 

https://i.imgur.com/xAR4LtR.png

Comment: @Remaldeep, Could you share a simple sample using one drive? So we could really reproduce this issue in our side.

Comment: That will be hard to do because it's an entire project with multiple small projects and I have no idea where it is going wrong. I could point you to the repo that has the error: 
https://github.com/SCIInstitute/fluorender
Let me know if it helps.

Comment: @Remaldeep, please right click the solution name and Clean the solution, or backup this solution, then create a new Blank solution, then move the projects one by one into this solution to analyze which project meet this issue.